# Unexpected behavior when making a variable-size, delayed framebuffer with queue

Tags: c++, opencv, queue, framebuffer, fifo

I am trying to make two left and right framebuffer queues, with live data from a stereo camera. On a key press, the framebuffers are emptied, and optionally either the left or right one is filled with a number of black frames, before the left and right cameras resume pushing to both queues at an equal rate, and the front of both queues are read and popped at an equal rate. This should result in, when the queue reaches the end of the black frames, the left and right buffers being out of sync by the number of black frames.

However, in my implementation, although the queue size is increased properly, and the black frames fill it properly, when the black frames are over, both buffers display frames from the same point in time (as I can see by the added frame numbers). Indeed, at that point every frame in the larger (delayed) buffer seems to be the same. What am I doing wrong in my implementation?

```
// Standard includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// ZED include
#include <sl/Camera.hpp>

// OpenCV include (for display)
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// Using std and sl namespaces
using namespace std;
using namespace sl;

// Sample functions
void updateCameraSettings(char key, sl::Camera &zed);
void switchCameraSettings();
void printHelp();

// Sample variables
CAMERA_SETTINGS camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_BRIGHTNESS;
string str_camera_settings = "BRIGHTNESS";
int step_camera_setting = 1;

//
//Create bias counters
int currentBias = 0;
int prevBias = 0;
bool change = false;




int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    InitParameters init_params;
    init_params.camera_resolution = RESOLUTION_VGA; // Use HD1080 video mode
    init_params.camera_fps = 0; // Set fps at 30
    init_params.depth_mode = DEPTH_MODE_NONE;

    // Create a ZED Camera object
    Camera zed;

    // Open the camera
    ERROR_CODE err = zed.open(init_params);
    if (err != SUCCESS) {
        cout << toString(err) << endl;
        zed.close();
        return 1; // Quit if an error occurred
    }

    // Print help in console
    printHelp();

    // Print camera information
    printf("ZED Model                 : %s\n", toString(zed.getCameraInformation().camera_model).c_str());
    printf("ZED Serial Number         : %d\n", zed.getCameraInformation().serial_number);
    printf("ZED Firmware              : %d\n", zed.getCameraInformation().firmware_version);
    printf("ZED Camera Resolution     : %dx%d\n", (int)zed.getResolution().width, (int)zed.getResolution().height);
    printf("ZED Camera FPS            : %d\n", (int)zed.getCameraFPS());

    // Create a Mat to store images
    cv::Mat stitchImage;
    Mat imageL;
    Mat imageR;
    cv::Mat tempL;
    cv::Mat tempR;
    cv::Mat blackScr;

    //Create framebuffer
    std::queue<cv::Mat> LeftQueue;
    std::queue<cv::Mat> RightQueue;
    std::queue<cv::Mat> emptyQueue;

    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;

    int frameInc = 0;

    // Capture new images until 'q' is pressed
    char key = ' ';
    while (key != 'q') {

        // Check that grab() is successful
        if (zed.grab() == SUCCESS) {
            // Retrieve left image
            zed.retrieveImage(imageL, VIEW_LEFT);
            zed.retrieveImage(imageR, VIEW_RIGHT);
            height = (int)imageL.getHeight();
            width = (int)imageL.getWidth();

            tempL = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, imageL.getPtr<sl::uchar1>(sl::MEM_CPU));
            tempR = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, imageR.getPtr<sl::uchar1>(sl::MEM_CPU));
            blackScr = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

            cv::putText(tempL, std::to_string(frameInc), cv::Point(30, 30), cv::FONT_ITALIC, .5, cv::Scalar(180, 180, 180), 1, CV_AA);
            cv::putText(tempR, std::to_string(frameInc), cv::Point(30, 30), cv::FONT_ITALIC, .5, cv::Scalar(180, 180, 180), 1, CV_AA);
            frameInc++;


            if (currentBias != prevBias) {
                std::cout << "Change detected! Making new framebuffers" << std::endl;
                LeftQueue = std::queue<cv::Mat>();
                RightQueue = std::queue<cv::Mat>();
                if (currentBias < 0) {
                    std::cout << "Biasing Left Eye!" << std::endl;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= abs(currentBias); i++) {

                        LeftQueue.push(blackScr);
                        std::cout << "LeftQueue: " << LeftQueue.size() << std::endl;
                    }
                    std::cout << "Current Bias is: " << currentBias << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "LeftQueue: " << LeftQueue.size() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "RightQueue: " << RightQueue.size() << std::endl;

                }
                else if (currentBias > 0) {
                    std::cout << "Biasing Right Eye!" << std::endl;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= abs(currentBias); i++) {

                        RightQueue.push(blackScr);
                        std::cout << "RightQueue: " << RightQueue.size() << std::endl;
                    }
                    std::cout << "Current Bias is: " << currentBias << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "LeftQueue: " << LeftQueue.size() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "RightQueue: " << RightQueue.size() << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Resetting to no delay!" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Current Bias is: " << currentBias << std::endl;


                    std::cout << "LeftQueue: " << LeftQueue.size() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "RightQueue: " << RightQueue.size() << std::endl;


                }
                prevBias = currentBias;
            }

            //Typical queue push
            LeftQueue.push(tempL);
            RightQueue.push(tempR);

            //Make OpenCV output
            cv::hconcat(LeftQueue.front(), RightQueue.front(), stitchImage);


            std::cout << "LeftFront: " << &LeftQueue.front() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "LeftBack: " << &LeftQueue.back() << std::endl;

            // Display image with OpenCV
            cv::imshow("VIEW", stitchImage);
            LeftQueue.pop();
            RightQueue.pop();
            key = cv::waitKey(5);

            // Change camera settings with keyboard
            updateCameraSettings(key, zed);
        }
        else
            key = cv::waitKey(5);
    }

    // Exit
    zed.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/**
    This function updates camera settings
 **/
void updateCameraSettings(char key, sl::Camera &zed) {
    int current_value;

    // Keyboard shortcuts
    switch (key) {

    case 'l':
        currentBias = currentBias - 10;
        std::cout << "Bias Delay Left by 10 Frames" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Current Bias is: " << currentBias << std::endl;
        break;

    case 'r':
        currentBias = currentBias + 10;
        std::cout << "Bias Delay Right by 10 Frames" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Current Bias is: " << currentBias << std::endl;
        break;



        // Switch to the next camera parameter
    case 's':
        switchCameraSettings();
        break;

        // Increase camera settings value ('+' key)
    case '+':
        current_value = zed.getCameraSettings(camera_settings_);
        zed.setCameraSettings(camera_settings_, current_value + step_camera_setting);
        std::cout << str_camera_settings << ": " << current_value + step_camera_setting << std::endl;
        break;

        // Decrease camera settings value ('-' key)
    case '-':
        current_value = zed.getCameraSettings(camera_settings_);
        if (current_value >= 1) {
            zed.setCameraSettings(camera_settings_, current_value - step_camera_setting);
            std::cout << str_camera_settings << ": " << current_value - step_camera_setting << std::endl;
        }
        break;

        // Reset to default parameters
    case 'x':
        currentBias = 0;
        std::cout << "Reset all settings to default" << std::endl;

        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_BRIGHTNESS, -1, true);
        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_CONTRAST, -1, true);
        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_HUE, -1, true);
        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_SATURATION, -1, true);
        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_GAIN, -1, true);
        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_EXPOSURE, -1, true);
        zed.setCameraSettings(sl::CAMERA_SETTINGS_WHITEBALANCE, -1, true);
        break;
    }
}

/**
    This function toggles between camera settings
 **/
void switchCameraSettings() {
    step_camera_setting = 1;
    switch (camera_settings_) {
    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_BRIGHTNESS:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_CONTRAST;
        str_camera_settings = "Contrast";
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: CONTRAST" << std::endl;
        break;

    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_CONTRAST:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_HUE;
        str_camera_settings = "Hue";
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: HUE" << std::endl;
        break;

    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_HUE:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_SATURATION;
        str_camera_settings = "Saturation";
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: SATURATION" << std::endl;
        break;

    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_SATURATION:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_GAIN;
        str_camera_settings = "Gain";
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: GAIN" << std::endl;
        break;

    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_GAIN:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_EXPOSURE;
        str_camera_settings = "Exposure";
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: EXPOSURE" << std::endl;
        break;

    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_EXPOSURE:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_WHITEBALANCE;
        str_camera_settings = "White Balance";
        step_camera_setting = 100;
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: WHITE BALANCE" << std::endl;
        break;

    case CAMERA_SETTINGS_WHITEBALANCE:
        camera_settings_ = CAMERA_SETTINGS_BRIGHTNESS;
        str_camera_settings = "Brightness";
        std::cout << "Camera Settings: BRIGHTNESS" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}

/**
    This function displays help
 **/
void printHelp() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Camera controls hotkeys: " << endl;
    cout << "  Increase camera settings value:            '+'" << endl;
    cout << "  Decrease camera settings value:            '-'" << endl;
    cout << "  Toggle camera settings:                    's'" << endl;
    cout << "  Reset all parameters:                      'r'" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Exit : 'q'" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. We cannot reproduce your issue without your hardware. Can you write a [mcve] which reproduces the issue, without requiring a camera and OpenCV for instance? By the way: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: So every frame in the delayed puffer is the same. Which frame number have those equal buffer-entries? The number 1 or the latest number? Can  you please give some more informations?